# How do I print out Bool values with words?

Tags: objective-c

For example I have this bool:

```
BOOL test = True;

NSLog("@ %d, test);
```

This will tell me that test has value 1.

How do I make it say test = true or any word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this....

'%d', 0 like false, 1 like true

```
BOOL b; 
NSLog(@"Bool value: %d",b);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"bool %s", b ? "true" : "false");
```

Hope i helped.

Comment: @user2384735 : What happen ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional:

```
NSLog(@"%s", test ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: I would perhaps use %@ and @"true" just to keep things consistent using ObjC objects/strings.

Comment: Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

BOOL is not an object, it is typedef'd to a primitive (can't remember which, not at a mac) with YES and NO defined as macros... 1 and 0 accordingly.

```
BOOL yesFlag = YES;
BOOL noFlag = NO;
NSLog(@"This string should end with NO: %@", noFlag?@"YES":@"NO");
NSLog(@"This string should end with YES:  %@", yesFlag?@"YES":@"NO");
```

for more information, please refer below link:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=643079

Answer (score 1):

The default value of **BOOL** variable is **NO** or **0**. In the background BOOL acts like an **int type** so you can use the `%i` or `%d` to view a BOOL type’s value or you can display text using a **ternary conditional operator** of the form: **`condition ? result_if_true : result_if_false`**

You can use the following code to find the value of BOOL variable.

**Declaration:**

```
bool boolVariable;
```

**To display integer value.**

```
NSLog(@"The value of bool is = %d",boolVariable);
```

**To display string value.**

```
NSLog(@"The value of bool is = %@", (boolVariable ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
// Or
NSLog(@"The value of bool is = %@", (boolVariable ? @"True" : @"False"));
```

Comment: Or i have found another work around:



 if (test == 1){
        NSLog(@"whatever the bool is suppose to do if yes");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"whatever the bool is suppose to do if no");
    }


Anyway thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @user2384735 that's what **condition ? result_if_true : result_if_false** does...just a simplified version for if-else.